# Ionic Capacitor Android: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found - Google Maps Plugin

Tags: android, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have recently tried to intergrate the new Google Maps capacitor plugin:
https://ionicframework.com/blog/announcing-the-capacitor-google-maps-plugin/

My app is a Ionic Capacitor application (Angular) and runs on android and iOS

This is my implementation:

.html:

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <div id="map" #map></div>
</ion-content>
```

.ts:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component} from '@angular/core';
import {GoogleMap} from '@capacitor/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-testpage',
  templateUrl: './testpage.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testpage.page.scss'],
})
export class TestPage implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  }

  public async showMap() {
    const apiKey = "myapikey";
    const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

    const mapConfig = {
      center: {
        lat: 33.6,
        lng: -117.9,
      },
      zoom: 8,
      androidLiteMode: false,
    }

    const mapOptions = {
      id: "my-map",
      apiKey: apiKey,
      config: mapConfig,
      element: mapElement,
    }
    const map = await GoogleMap.create(mapOptions)

  }
}
```

in my android manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="myapikey"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

However when I open the page I get the following errors in the console:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.

W/SnapshotHandler: Unable to retrieve flag snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.mypackagename, using defaults.


 java.io.FileNotFoundException:/data/user/0/com.gmail.mypackagename/files/phenotype/shared/com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.mypackagename.pb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

W/MobStoreFlagStore: Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.mypackagename, may result in stale flags.

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.mypackagename, sha256=[...], atk=false, ver=221514044.true (go/gsrlt)
```

I am wondering if anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: I had the same FileNotFoundException working on native android app, it turns out that I misplaced the api meta-data, it should be inside the application element.
   ```<application
     ....>
   <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
</application>```

hope it helps

Comment: Same here. API_KEY is inside the <application> tag

Comment: To all in my comments, I have given up trying to make this work. Also I found that if I use this then I have to pay Google for the API. Instead as I only need the google maps tiles/ looks,  I am using leaflet with a google maps tiles package https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant